# python-pptx: adding slide hyperlinks to table cells

Tags: python, python-pptx

the library's click_action feature is only supported for `BaseShape` class members (which a table cell, its text frame, paragraphs and runs are not). Meanwhile a text run's `hyperlink` attribute only supports setting of external (web-)links. How to add an internal link to a slide within a table, such as to create a table-of-contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code solves the question above:

```
from lxml import etree  # type: ignore
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE  # type: ignore

def link_table_cell_to_slide(table_shape, cell, slide):
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    rel_id = table_shape._parent.part.relate_to(slide.part, RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.SLIDE)
    link_run = cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
    nsmap = link_run._r.nsmap
    # trying to do it with format strings and escaping curly braces
    # was not doable with pylint (unignorable syntax error)
    ns_a = '{' + nsmap['a'] + '}'
    ns_r = '{' + nsmap['r'] + '}'
    run_properties = link_run._r.find(f'{ns_a}rPr')
    hlink = etree.SubElement(run_properties, f'{ns_a}hlinkClick')
    hlink.set('action', 'ppaction://hlinksldjump')
    hlink.set(f'{ns_r}id', rel_id)

# ... determining the toc_shape, row in the table to link up as well as
# the target slide to link to
link_table_cell_to_slide(toc_shape, row.cells[0], target_slide)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It hadn't occurred to me that table cells' runs couldn't be hyperlinked to other slides. And you've taught me some techniques for lxml that might help my md2pptx (Markdown to PowerPoint via python-pptx) project.